# Pacemaker: adding custom resource

Tags: high-availability, heartbeat, pacemaker

I am trying to create an HA cluster with Pacemaker on CentOS7.
One of the required resources is a custom service. I have an LSB-compliant init script that I have put into /etc/init.d, and I have it listed when running:

```
pcs resource agents lsb:heartbeat
```

When I try to add the resource with

```
pcs resource create MyServer lsb:heartbeat:MyServer target_role=started resource_failure_stickiness=-INFINITY op monitor interval=30s op start timeout=180s op stop timeout=180s op status timeout=15 --group AllResources
```

The error I get:

```
Error: Unable to create resource 'lsb:heartbeat:MyServer', it is not installed on this system (use --force to override)
```

If I run it with --force, I get the following:

```
Call cib_replace failed (-203): Update does not conform to the configured schema
```

The group AllResources has other two resources: Ping and IPAddr2, that were added in a similar way with no errors.

What am I missing? Anyone faced something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that unlike Heartbeat, in Pacemaker the form in which we address a custom LSB script is lsb:MyServer.
The working command would be:

```
pcs resource create MyServer lsb:MyServer target_role=started resource_failure_stickiness=-INFINITY op monitor interval=30s op start timeout=180s op stop timeout=180s op status timeout=15 --group AllResources
```